# Modulus of an integer

Tags: c++, int, switch-statement, modulo

I'm writing a program that gets a dollar amount from input and displays the amount in words. Unable to use strings, arrays, or functions at this point, so I've worked it out with switch structures, though it's not very efficient.

However my problem comes with when I've converted the input from a float to an integer, and trying to single out the digits after the decimal point using modulus; for some reason it doesn't return the correct digit.

So say for 321.78
extracting the 1st decimal(or 8) it returns a 7. I'm not too sure why this happens, and how too fix it.

Here is my code for the first part

```
float number;
int digit1, digit2, digit3, decimals, decimal1, decimal2, int_number;

cout << "Enter a dollar amount from 0-1000: ";
cin >> number;

int_number = number * 100;

digit1 = (int_number % 1000)/100; //ones
digit2 = (int_number % 10000)/1000; //tens
digit3 = (int_number % 100000)/10000; // hundreds

decimal1 = int_number % 10;
decimal2 = (int_number % 100)/10;
```

The decimal1 should return a 8 if input is 321.78. Have I missed something?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try printing `int_number`.

Comment: I too suspect this is a precision issue. Better use `double` than `float`

Comment: If you want the user to enter `321.78` but have it as the `int` value `32178`, I recommend not going through a `float` to get there. Really, you want to read it in as a string, parse it to remove the `.` and check for format errors, then convert the string `32178` to an `int`. Taking a `float` as input is basically telling the user that they must enter a representable floating point value.

Comment: if input is 321.78 int_number becomes 32178 which is an integer so i could use the modulus. Even then shouldn't it still return 8?
32178 % 10 = 8?

Comment: @KingKong Did you actually try printing it out? I suspect it is 32177.

Comment: @sftrabbit unfortunately im not allowed too use strings in this excersise

Comment: @sftrabbit you were right, it is 32177. not too sure why that happens 0.0

Comment: @syam no. doubles may be less prone to precision issues, but they still have them.

Comment: @ArneMertz yeah but since OP has so many restrictions on what he can use, I hardly see any other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just like converting 1.5 to an integer: the result type doesn't have enough precision to represent the original value exactly. Same thing with 321.78: floating-point values cannot represent that value exactly, and you end up with a value that's slightly smaller than you expected, i.e., 321.77#### where the #### represents additional decimal digits that are too tedious to calculate here. When that value is multiplied by 100 and converted to int it gets truncated, and 32177.#### becomes 32177.

EDIT: forgot to mention the solution.

```
int dollars;
int cents;
char dp;
std::cin >> dollars;
std::cin >> dp;
std::cin >> cents;
cents += dollars * 100;
```

Error checking is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks heaps, i didn't know that happened. Thanks for explaining it!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, please bookmark [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Your problem is with floating point precision. Try the following simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    float f;
    std::cin >> f;
    int x = f * 100;
    std::cout << x;
}
```

You will see that `x` has value `32177`. This is caused because floating point types only have a certain amount of precision. The closest representable value to `321.78` that a `float` can have is `321.779998779296875`. As you can see, this is slightly less than `321.78`. When you multiply this by 100, you have something a little less than `32178` which when converted to `int` has value `32177`.

The problem here is really that you are asking the user for a `float` value. Since you are extracting directly into a `float`, you are putting the limitation on the user that they can only enter values that are representable by `float`. Obviously this is very silly since you only end up converting that value to an `int`. Imagine an ATM did this! There would be many lost pennies. Instead, the correct approach here is to read the input as a string and parse into the appropriate `int` value.

Comment: well that explains it haha. Thanks heaps for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Any floating point type of limited precision is prone to rounding errors (google a bit, you will get tons of information about those issues).

There are half-baked solutions like `floor (number * 100 + 0.5)`, but those still suffer from rounding errors in special cases and/or might give different results on different platforms.

In the case of currencies with limited decimals I would not bother use floating point numbers and mess around with them - just read the input as a string and parse it correctly in the first place, ommiting anything related to float/double and their issues. They are just not the right datatype for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer, based on the comment by sftrabbit:

```
#include<cstring>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  string str1;
  cout << "enter number:";
  cin  >> str1;

  //READ AS A STRING AND REMOVE '.'

  str1.erase(std::remove(str1.begin(), str1.end(), '.'), str1.end());

  //CAST STRING TO VALUE
  int value = atoi(str1.c_str());

  //LOOP THROUGH THE PROCESS YOUR WERE DOING BEFORE
  int divisor = 10;
  int  counter = 1;
  while(divisor < 10*value){

    cout << "Digit " << counter << " = " << value%divisor/(divisor/10) << endl;
    divisor *=10;
    counter++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to extract the digit one by one you can do this:
int_number = number * 100;

```
hundreds = int_number / 10000;
tens = (int_number - hundreds*10000) / 1000;
ones = (int_number - hundreds*10000 - tens * 1000) / 100
decimal1= (int_number - hundreds*10000 - tens * 1000 - ones * 100) / 10;
decimal2= int_number - hundreds*10000 - tens * 1000 - ones * 100 - decimal1 * 10;
```

Comment: i don't think there is a precision floating issue for a value with 2 digit after comma

Comment: I can assure you there is. 2 digits in powers of 10 can be endless periodics in powers of 2. 321.78 is 321.7799987792968750... as a float and 321.7799999999999727... as a double.

Answer (score 0):

321.78 can't be exactly represented in the float domain. your cast

```
int_number = number * 100;
```

just removes the last digits and performs no rounding. try

```
int_number = static_cast<int> (floor (number * 100 + 0.5f))
```

instead.

Comment: so its a precision issue because my expression didn't round the numbers off properly?

could you also help explain why the +0.5?

Comment: @KingKong the 0.5 trick might work often, but not in every case. There still will be cases where you are one digit off. Simply don't use floats for fixed point calculations.